# Error getting large content from Chrome with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I implemented a Selenium WebDriver test case to read the content of a JavaScript variable using Google Chrome as browser. The content of this variable can be very large since it's a Base64 String obtained from a Blob object. WebDriver stops working logging this trace:

```
[1080,058][SEVERE]: Too large write data is pending: size=118624364, max_buffer_size=104857600
```

Does anyone knows how to increase this limit (`max_buffer_size`) in a Chrome browser managed by WebDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to change that value (`max_buffer_size`) in a running instance of Chrome. I got that answer in the [Chromium forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/U5qyeX_ydBo).

Answer (score 1):

We got around this by editing [this line](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/server/chromedriver_server.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=53) in Chromium to be minorly greater than the size of the raw text in bytes (string/char types used in C++) and compiling for Chromedriver target!

`// Replace x with just under your max size.
const int kBufferSize = x * 1024 * 1024;  // x MB`

We followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841415/build-chromedriver-for-linux) for compiling.

```
# Install Chromium build dependencies.
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list # && dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git build-essential clang curl

# Install Chromium's depot_tools.
export DEPOT_TOOLS=/usr/bin/depot_tools

git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git $DEPOT_TOOLS

export PATH=$PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS
echo -e "\n# Add Chromium's depot_tools to the PATH." >> .bashrc
echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS\"" >> .bashrc

git config --global https.postBuffer 1048576000

# Download Chromium sources.
fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium

cd <directory-installed>

gclient runhooks

cd src

build/install-build-deps.sh --no-prompt

gn gen out/Release --args="is_debug=false"
ninja -C out/Release chromedriver

cp out/Release/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver

cd <wherever>
```

I guess the proper solution would be to have Chromium http server properly chunk this data to the buffer but I need to look into this a bit further.

Comment: Could you make your answer more self contained? In particular, the link for "this line" dying would severely damage the answer.

Comment: Can do! Yep, so sorry. I'm a newb on Stack Overflow so sincere apologies.