# Build chromedriver for linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build chromedriver from source for use in selenium for Linux.
i use this manual https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md
but when i build without any error my chromedriver less for 2mb that if i download form google code site. and this chromedriver not work with selenium. just blank error.
Have someone any idea what wrong? Thank You

Answer (score 3):

We'd need more information... Here is a dockerfile (largely taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/tabiodun/e4204ab83b3b7cfd2d28b478cf441162)) that worked for me. Most of the commands come from the chromium [build docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md).

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install Chromium build dependencies.
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list # && dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git build-essential clang curl

# Install Chromium's depot_tools.
ENV DEPOT_TOOLS /usr/bin/depot_tools
RUN git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git $DEPOT_TOOLS
ENV PATH $PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS
RUN echo -e "\n# Add Chromium's depot_tools to the PATH." >> .bashrc
RUN echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$DEPOT_TOOLS\"" >> .bashrc

RUN git config --global https.postBuffer 1048576000

# Download Chromium sources.
RUN fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium

WORKDIR /

RUN gclient runhooks

WORKDIR src

RUN build/install-build-deps.sh --no-prompt

RUN gn gen out/Release --args="is_debug=false"
RUN ninja -C out/Release chromedriver

RUN cp out/Release/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver

WORKDIR /
```

Comment: do you have for mac ?