# Investing.com blocking Python Selenium Script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download portfolio data from my own login from https://www.investing.com/portfolio by automating using Selenium webdriver for Chrome using Python.

It was working till few days back.
Suddenly it has stopped working., it seems the website is detecting the automation and preventing it.

Below is a very basic code which takes to the Login Page and waits for the user to input credentials.

Once the user inputs its credentials and clicks on sign in - nothing happens.
upon investigating i found that the javascript which signs in - is being blocked - 403 error.

From Development Tools under networks,
https://www.investing.com/members-admin/auth/signInByEmail/ this javascripts gives an error
The preview of above file shows : Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue while in selenium but when using normal chrome shows:
{response: "Invalid_Email_Pwd", msg: "Wrong email or password. Try again."}
msg
:
"Wrong email or password. Try again."
response
:
"Invalid_Email_Pwd"

Is it that the website is blocking the selenium automation?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

opt.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)  # 16

driver.get(r'https://www.investing.com/portfolio');
assert 'Portfolio & Watchlist - Investing.com' in driver.title
print('Opened site successfully')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginFormUser_email')))
username.send_keys("", 'username@gmail.com')
print('Entered UserID')
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginForm_password')))
password.send_keys("", 'password')
print('Entered Password')
time.sleep(4000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.removeScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"identifier":"1"})
```

adding above line helped after the driver was defined

this was taken from here [Selenium does not work with a chromedriver modified to avoid detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770608/selenium-does-not-work-with-a-chromedriver-modified-to-avoid-detection)